# My hard disk converted from ntfs tp raw. Can it be recovered in Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

In my internal hard disk suddenly this message appeared  at boot 
 (A disk read error occurred Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to restart ) in Windows 7

I have connected it as external hd to another laptop. I can see the partitions but it asks me  to format it and when I want to make `chkdsk` it says not supported for RAW .

Is there any way to recover it in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

If you were doing anything before the restart, that could have screwed up the disk. I have seen bad defragmenting, partition resizing and moving screw up drive formats. If you haven't been doing stuff like that, you can try looking into using a disk diagnostic tool such as GParted (which I would recommend, because it will give you more specific details than any stuff Microsoft gives) to figure out if there are any specific issues with say, the boot sector of the disk, etc.

If your diagnostic tool pulls up a lot of errors, then the drive may simply be FUBAR, so you might have to just chuck it.

Comment: In general, try to avoid asking questions in your answers (use comments for that). Otherwise - you got a +1.

Comment: is there any other solutions ? please

Comment: Hi, please could some one see this pictures , i have connected my hard to Puppy Linux,
it has read my hard drive partitions but displayed error message .